# Where to add the permalink in this function?

Tags: functions, permalinks, comments

Below is a function that displays the latest 4 approved comments on my homepage, I wrote this almost a year ago, and for the life of me, it's gone completely from my head, All i want to do is add a permalink to where the comment is located. How do I, and where do I add this?

```
function showLatestComments() {
  global $wpdb;  
  $sql = "
   SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved, SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,100) AS com_excerpt 
   FROM $wpdb->comments 
   WHERE comment_approved = '1'
   ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC 
   LIMIT 4";  
 $comments = $wpdb->get_results($sql);  
 $output .= '<img src="/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/student-perspectives.jpg" /><h2>Latest student perspectives</h2>
 <ul id="comm">';  
 foreach ($comments as $comment) { 
   $output .= '<li><strong>'. $comment->comment_author . ' said</strong> : "' . strip_tags($comment->com_excerpt). '..."</li>';
   }
 $output .= '</ul>';  
 echo $output;  
}

//end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [`get_comment_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_link) function in your `foreach` loop like so:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) { 
    $output .= '<li><strong>'
            . $comment->comment_author
            . ' said</strong> : "'
            . '<a href="'
            . get_comment_link( $comment->comment_post_ID )
            . '">'
            . strip_tags($comment->com_excerpt)
            . '..."</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it just strings aload of random urls together that aren't actually close to the links of the comments, is their no way of getting a simple permalink or post ID of comment other than the way above?